# open a specific location in the file explorer

Tags: linux

Hey I am new to linux and I am using RHEL5 on my desktop.

I wanted to ask, what would be a quick way to open a specific file location in the file explorer window. 
I know that you can point to it via the terminal, but I want to "quick access" the location.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try Ctrl + L ? which is open location

Comment: I found the answer from Lakshitha. Thanks. If you answer the question formally I can mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to open the location.

(Credit goes to Lakshitha Ranasingha. I wrote the answer only to minimize the number of unanswered questions.)